# Redirection issues of cart and wishlist when remove item in magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, wishlist, delete, redirection

I have an issue like, I have multiple items in cart or wishlist but once I remove any item from it, it will redirect to Home Page not on the same page (This issue will occur on my live site).

But On my Local server it is working fine when I remove any item I will redirect me to cart page again not on home Page.

Why this happens?

Comment: Did you try this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12426626/magento-redirects-to-homepage-after-item-removed-from-cart

Comment: Why I need to overwrite controller because everything is working fine on my local server

Comment: Did you check with all the third party extensions (as used in live site) enabled in local server?

Comment: Yes, Every extension  is same and enabled on both site.

Comment: Did you checked whether the configurations are same in both sites?